# MPI_Send(109): Invalid rank has value -2 but must be nonnegative and less than 1

Tags: c++, mpi

Could anyone help me to find the below errors in my code:

> "Fatal error in MPI_Send: Invalid rank, error stack:
>   MPI_Send(190): MPI_Send(buf=0x1123060, count=40, MPI_FLOAT, dest=MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag=25, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
>   MPI_Send(109): Invalid rank has value -2 but must be nonnegative and less than 1"

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    name = "quick.dat";
    n = 40;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    int i;
    double sp;
    double *ap, *ae, *aw, *aww, *cte;
    ap = new double[n];
    ae = new double[n];
    aw = new double[n];
    aww = new double[n];
    cte = new double[n];

    int my_rank, nproc;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);

    if (my_rank == 0)
    {
        MPI_Send(&ap[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&ae[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&aw[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&aww[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&cte[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        for (i = 0; i < (n - 1) / nproc + 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                ae[i] = a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) +
                        1. / 3.0 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) -
                        3.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                cte[i] = -(8. / 3. * a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) +
                           2.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) +
                           a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
                ap[i] = -(ae[i] - cte[i] + a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                          a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
                continue;
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                aw[i] = a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        7. / 8. * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        1.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                cte[i] = 0.25 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n);
                ae[i] = a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                        3.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                ap[i] = -(ae[i] + aw[i] - cte[i] + a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                          a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
                continue;
            }
            if (i == n - 1)
            {
                aw[i] = a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        1. / 3.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) +
                        6.0 / 8.0 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n);
                aww[i] = -1.0 / 8.0 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n);
                cte[i] = 0;
                sp = 8.0 / 3.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                     a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                ap[i] = -(aww[i] + aw[i] + sp + a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                          a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
                continue;
            }
            if (i != 0 && i != 1 && i != n - 1)
            {
                ae[i] = a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                        3.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                aw[i] = a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        6. / 8. * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        1.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                aww[i] = -1.0 / 8.0 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n);
                cte[i] = 0;
                ap[i] = -(aww[i] + aw[i] + ae[i] - cte[i] +
                          a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                          a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
            }
        }
        MPI_Recv(&ap[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&ae[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&aw[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&aww[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&cte[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }

    else if (my_rank != 0 && my_rank != nproc - 1)
    {
        MPI_Recv(&ap[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&ae[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&aw[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&aww[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&cte[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        for (i = ((n - 1) / nproc) * my_rank + 1; i < ((n - 1) / nproc) * (my_rank + 1) + 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                ae[i] = a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) +
                        1. / 3.0 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) -
                        3.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                cte[i] = -(8. / 3. * a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) +
                           2.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) +
                           a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
                ap[i] = -(ae[i] - cte[i] + a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                          a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
                continue;
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                aw[i] = a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        7. / 8. * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        1.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                cte[i] = 0.25 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n);
                ae[i] = a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                        3.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                ap[i] = -(ae[i] + aw[i] - cte[i] + a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                          a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
                continue;
            }
            if (i == n - 1)
            {
                aw[i] = a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        1. / 3.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) +
                        6.0 / 8.0 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n);
                aww[i] = -1.0 / 8.0 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n);
                cte[i] = 0;
                sp = 8.0 / 3.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                     a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                ap[i] = -(aww[i] + aw[i] + sp + a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                          a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
                continue;
            }
            if (i != 0 && i != 1 && i != n - 1)
            {
                ae[i] = a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                        3.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                aw[i] = a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        6. / 8. * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        1.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                aww[i] = -1.0 / 8.0 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n);
                cte[i] = 0;
                ap[i] = -(aww[i] + aw[i] + ae[i] - cte[i] +
                          a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                          a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
            }
        }
        MPI_Send(&ap[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&ae[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&aw[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&aww[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&cte[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else if (my_rank == nproc - 1 && nproc != 1)
    {
        MPI_Recv(&ap[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&ae[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&aw[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&aww[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&cte[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 25, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        for (i = ((n - 1) / nproc) * my_rank + 1; i < n; i++)
        {

            if (i == 0)
            {
                ae[i] = a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) +
                        1. / 3.0 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) -
                        3.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                cte[i] = -(8. / 3. * a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) +
                           2.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) +
                           a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
                ap[i] = -(ae[i] - cte[i] + a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                          a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
                continue;
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                aw[i] = a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        7. / 8. * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        1.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                cte[i] = 0.25 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n);
                ae[i] = a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                        3.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                ap[i] = -(ae[i] + aw[i] - cte[i] + a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                          a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
                continue;
            }
            if (i == n - 1)
            {
                aw[i] = a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        1. / 3.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) +
                        6.0 / 8.0 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n);
                aww[i] = -1.0 / 8.0 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n);
                cte[i] = 0;
                sp = 8.0 / 3.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                     a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                ap[i] = -(aww[i] + aw[i] + sp + a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                          a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
                continue;
            }
            if (i != 0 && i != 1 && i != n - 1)
            {
                ae[i] = a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * D((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                        3.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                aw[i] = a(i * 1.0 / n) * D(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        6. / 8. * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n) +
                        1.0 / 8.0 * a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n);
                aww[i] = -1.0 / 8.0 * a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n);
                cte[i] = 0;
                ap[i] = -(aww[i] + aw[i] + ae[i] - cte[i] +
                          a((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) * u((i + 1) * 1.0 / n) -
                          a(i * 1.0 / n) * u(i * 1.0 / n));
            }
        }
        MPI_Send(&ap[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&ae[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&aw[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&aww[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&cte[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    //  double t22 = MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Finalize();

    //  printf("[IJK]   Compute time [s]   : %6.3f \n", t22-t11 );

    iteration(aww, aw, ap, ae, cte);

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    std::cout << "Time to Execute the FVM code "
              << " is : " << diff.count() << " s\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While the answer is quite obvious in your case, you should really spend more effort in preparing your question. Format both the question and the code properly, chose appropriate tags, and most importantly reduce your code to a [mcve] - do not get into the habit of just dumping your code and error here!

Answer (score 0):

The message is actually rather clear: `MPI_Send: Invalid rank`. You cannot specify `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` as a destination rank for `MPI_Send`. In point to point communication, there must be one specific receiver. It seems you want to use the collective `MPI_Bcast`, e.g.:

```
MPI_Send(&ap[0], n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

This should be run on all ranks exactly like that.

Comment: Thank you Zulan for your help, I did as Zulan told and I got some other errors for running with two cores: "Fatal error in MPI_Init: Internal MPI error!, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(483): 
MPID_Init(363).......: channel initialization failed
(unknown)(): Internal MPI error!" does anyone know what is the problem? I am beginner with MPI.